# How can i give discount for customers when cart subtotal reaches a specific amount in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, shopping-cart

In magento 2 how can i give discount for customers when the cart amount reaches a specififc amount?can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create cart price rules.

> Admin -> Marketing -> Cart Price Rules

You can get more idea about how to set cart price rule . Please follow on this 
[link](https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-create-a-cart-price-rule-in-magento-2.html) or this [magento dev doc](http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rules-cart.html)